# JSONATA - how to create new json objects from an existing json object

Tags: json, architecture, software-design, jsonata

I have to create JSON objects from the main JSON object. I have to add, delete, and update the components from the main JSON object to create new JSON objects. What is the best command to accomplish this suing JSONATA?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the transform operator: https://docs.jsonata.org/other-operators#-------transform